# Updating editable cell in primefaces datatable via javascript

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using Primefaces 3.2/JSF 2.0. I have an In-Cell editable data table. When, i go into Edit mode, I have an input box and a button,When i click on the button, it opens up a dialog with a single selection data table. Once a row is selected,i update the entire data table which reverts back to the read-only view.

i would like to update the editable cell with a value from my callback function. So that the data table remains in editable mode, Since the id of the cell has the row index in it, i am not sure how i can get that id, so that i can update my input box

**Here is my page**

```
<h:panelGroup id="placesTable">
     <h:form id="placesform" prependId="false" method="post" > 
        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{placesBean.items}"   id="placesList" widgetvar="placesListVar" editable="true">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{placesBean.saveRow}" />
...
<p:column headerText="Select Country" style="width:125px" nowrap="nowrap">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.country}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="countryInput"  value="#{item.country}" style="float:left"/>
                <h:outputLink style="float:left" value="javascript:void(0)" onclick="countrySelectDialog.show()">   
                    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/select-icon.png" />
                </h:outputLink>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
```

**My selector dialog's listener looks like this**
I am using a composite component for my selector

```
<p:dialog id="countrySelectDialog" header="Indicator Groups"  height="250" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">
        <h:form prependId="false">
            <selector:countrySelect data="#{countrySelector.countries}" selection="#{placesBean.selectedCountry}">
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{placesBean.processSelection}" value="Ok" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-search" oncomplete="countrySelectDialog.hide()" update=":placesTable" process="@form"/>

                </f:facet>              
            </selector:countrySelect>
        </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

The id of my input box comes out like this
**placesList:0:countryInput**, how do i get this id in my ajax callback so that i can update this cell rather than updating the entire data table. This will ensure that my table is still in editable mode and then the data will be saved when the rowEdit event is handled.

Comment: Till the rowEdit is complete and the validation is complete, for all purposes you need to refer placesBean but not the dataTable. Once validation is successful, need to update the dataTable there by comming out of edit mode.

Comment: But, how do i update the input box in the editable cell after the countryselect command button is clicked? If i can get a handle on the row index, then i can use javascript to update that field. I am not sure how the row number can be passed around from the command button.

Comment: In dataTable, add attribute rowIndexVar like this ... <p:dataTable rowIndexVar="rowIndex"> and the rowIndex can be used as a parameter in any client call (javascript) like ..... '#{rowIndex}'